# crash while removing cell from table view

Tags: ios, tableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        //Get the object to delete from the array.
        NSLog(@"%@",[[_arrayForTable valueForKey:@"IDS"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] );

        NSInteger myInteger = [[[_arrayForTable valueForKey:@"IDS"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] integerValue];
      NSNumber *selRow = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myInteger];
        NSLog(@"%@",selRow);
        [self removeCell:selRow]; // this is working perfectly it gets remove from database

        //Delete the object from the table.
        // app get crash here crash report is pested below 
        [self.table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
}

- (void) removeCell:(NSNumber *)selRow{

       NSLog(@"_arrayForTable%@",_arrayForTable);
 NSInteger myInteger = [selRow integerValue];

    [_arrayForTable removeObjectAtIndex:myInteger];

    NSLog(@"_arrayForTable%@",_arrayForTable);



    if(deleteStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "delete from PersonNamesAndBirthDates where ID = ?";
        NSLog(@"%s",sql);
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, sql, -1, &deleteStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database1));
    }
    NSLog(@"%d",myInteger);

    //When binding parameters, index starts from 1 and not zero.
    sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStmt, 1, myInteger );

    if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteStmt)) 
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database1));

    sqlite3_reset(deleteStmt);
}
```

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:1046 2013-04-08
>   17:01:13.069 birthdate reminder 2[583:15803] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (12) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (12), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

please suggest something

my numberofrow method is below

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.


    return _arrayForTable.count;

}
```

app is not crashing everytime sometime works sometime crash

Comment: paste your numnerOfRows method ?

Comment: My guess is that your assumption about `removeCell:`, that it is working perfectly, might be the problem. The row might be deleted from your database, but have you checked your variable `_arrayForTable`? It seems, it's still in there.

Comment: it gets deleted. but sometime it shows count right sometime wrong. when app get launch again then _arrayForTable is correct i dont understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so as I see it, you are getting the ID of a specific row with:

```
NSInteger myInteger = 
    [[[_arrayForTable valueForKey:@"IDS"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] integerValue];
NSNumber *selRow = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myInteger];
```

And then, you're using the ID of that specific row, as the index to remove it from the array.

```
NSInteger myInteger = [selRow integerValue];
[_arrayForTable removeObjectAtIndex:myInteger];
```

That's where things go wrong. If the array has the same order as your TableView, you need to remove `indexPath.row` from it. The ID is necessary for your database.

Comment: yes i got it. i wanted to post answer but i dont have points thank u so much:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle :(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        //Get the object to delete from the array.
        NSLog(@"%@",[[_arrayForTable valueForKey:@"IDS"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] );

        NSInteger myInteger = [[[_arrayForTable valueForKey:@"IDS"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] integerValue];
        NSNumber *selRow = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myInteger];
        NSLog(@"%@",selRow);

        [self.table beginUpdates];        

        [self removeCell:selRow]; // this is working perfectly it gets remove from database

        //Delete the object from the table.
        // app get crash here crash report is pested below 
        [self.table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [self.table endUpdates];

    }
}
```

Notice the `[self.table beginUpdates];` and `[self.table endUpdates];` around the lines of code which alter the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

IT"S WORKING
at and of your commitEditingStyle method add this line

```
[TableViewForFirstView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```